# Comparing different degrees of fitting curves on a dataset

Tags: python, non-linear-regression

I have a data set including two columns (X,y) and 40 rows and I want to fit different degrees of curves on them and plot the fitted curve in each degree and also report the MSE, bias and variance.
I have tried some different ways to do that but I couldn't get to do.
this is the last code that I've wrote:

```
error_list=[]
bias_list=[]
variance_list=[]
degrees=range(1,5)
for degree in degrees:
    polybig_features = PolynomialFeatures(degree=degree, include_bias=False)
    lin_regressor = LinearRegression()
    polynomial_regression  = Pipeline([("poly_features", polybig_features),("lin_regressor", lin_regressor)])

    polynomial_regression.fit(X, y)
 
    y_predict= polynomial_regression.predict(X)

    error = mean_squared_error(y, y_predict)

    error_list.append(error)

    bias_list.append(abs(((mean_squared_error(y, y_predict))-(np.var(y_predict)))))

    variance_list.append(np.var(y_predict))
```

when I run this code, there is an error:
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[668.58280529 705.75796236 564.06655505 343.56372894 435.47617559
472.82049085 569.01256811 613.4781096  616.97221213 496.23507759
574.41279817 749.82431162 485.46271622 637.94586599 217.97808332
446.72627939 305.0999983  769.37229498 446.49444799 351.53611647
272.65144959 131.61943471 503.31284932 651.26251427 240.31124596
224.99940286 428.59574126 158.64148488 851.62188255 742.63808985
758.03190387 662.66266054 690.64505953 800.25129682 801.18943617
228.46683905 234.1316092  114.61896035 343.96053609 500.84073958].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
I don't know how to fix it. please let me know if you have any idea about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

All you will need to do is reshape your `X` using `X.reshape(-1,1)` seeing as how you only have a single feature. This works if it is already a numpy array, otherwise you will need to do something like `np.array(X).reshape(-1, 1)`.

so your final code could look something like this

```
error_list=[]
bias_list=[]
variance_list=[]

# Add this line
X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, 1)

degrees=range(1,5)
for degree in degrees:
    polybig_features = PolynomialFeatures(degree=degree, include_bias=False)
    lin_regressor = LinearRegression()
    polynomial_regression  = Pipeline([("poly_features", polybig_features),("lin_regressor", lin_regressor)])

    polynomial_regression.fit(X, y)
 
    y_predict= polynomial_regression.predict(X)

    error = mean_squared_error(y, y_predict)

    error_list.append(error)

    bias_list.append(abs(((mean_squared_error(y, y_predict))-(np.var(y_predict)))))

    variance_list.append(np.var(y_predict))
```